# How to pass two or more parameters using julienschmidt/httprouter in golang?

Tags: rest, go, routes

I am new to golang and using julienschmidt/httprouter for routing.
    based on below snippet, able to send one parameter.
    but I am little confused to send multiple parameters, cloud anyone helps me.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Welcome!\n")
}

func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, %s!\n", ps.ByName("name"))
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Index)
    router.GET("/hello/:name", Hello)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add in another parameter:

```
router.GET("/hello/:first_name/:last_name", Hello)

func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, %s %s!\n", ps.ByName("first_name"), ps.ByName("last_name"))
}
```